# Site selector control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, branding

I'm trying to implement a drop down list within a custom master page using sharepoint 2010.  The customised dropdown should allow users to select a particar site.  There needs to be a level of flexibility so users can update the sites listed in the drop down say via a list etc as some sites are external

Could this just be a custom web user control coded to look at a site list which the masterpage can then reference?

Any ideas on how best to approach or any ootb approach on this much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to add a listview webpart on master page and change its xslt to display all list values in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new sitemap file with your links.

Add the provider to your web.config.

Change your masterpage's navigation datasource to your new provider.

To add new links you can just insert new entries into your sitemap xml file.

regards,

KS